# Error: /VERSION: No such file or directory error in phonegap2.0 xcode 4.3

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I am very new to iPhone development and also I am looking to work with the PhoneGap framework to create iPhone apps. I have created HTML, JavaScript in my PhoneGap project. I got this error:

```
 "error: /VERSION: No such file or directory"
```

when running it in XCode 4.3 after installing Phonegap 2.0 on my Mac.

I have searched Google to solve this error, but I can't find any idea from there. Could you please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance. Looking forward your answers.

Answer (score 0):

The VERSION file reference is missing in the "Resources" group. For me, it was because I hadn't installed PhoneGap yet and thus the CordovaLib project was missing (if it doesn't work after installing PhoneGap from the *dmg* file, reboot your Mac).

If you deleted the VERSION file like I said in my previously wrong answer, compilation works but then the application throws an "error attempt to insert nil value (key: cordova)" (but HTML displays correctly). Add back the reference (just revert the pbxproj file), it must point to the VERSION file in the CordovaLib project.

---

In later versions of PhoneGap, the dependency on the VERSION file was [removed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1166) and the whole CordovaLib dependency handling was simplified by the bundled scripts which can update your Xcode project automatically.